# angular-parse argument is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

This is my first time using angular and parse.com.
And I got this error

> Argument 'eventList' is not a function, got undefined

when trying to run this angular code:

```
var main_app = angular.module('getParse', []);
main_app.controller('eventList', function() {
var mainTable = document.getElementById("mainTable");
mainTable.hidden = true;
Parse.Cloud.run("MJSEvent_All",{}, {
    success: function(results) {
        //console.log(eventObj);
        var objects = results['objects'];

        for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(objects[i].get('title')));
            tr.appendChild(td)

            var speakerObj = objects[i].get('session2')[0].get('speaker2')[0];
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(speakerObj.get('displayName')));
            tr.appendChild(td)

            mainTable.appendChild(tr);
        }
    },
    error: function(errorObj) {
        console.log(errorObj);
    }
});});
```

and this is my html code

```
<div class="row" ng-app="getParse" ng-controller="eventList">
    <h3>Event List</h3>
    <table border=1 id="mainTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Speaker</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

anyone can help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Need more code. It's works on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1nmsrm0/)

```
<div class="row" ng-app="getParse" ng-controller="eventList">
<h3>Event List</h3>
  <table border=1 id="mainTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Speaker</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>


<script>var main_app = angular.module('getParse', []);
main_app.controller('eventList', function() {
  var mainTable = document.getElementById("mainTable");
  mainTable.hidden = true;
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have change my code, but the error change to another error.
I found out that I have to include Parse App key and Parse JS key in the angular module, not in separate js file/script.
The error have been solved, now I can get the object i need from that Parse cloud code